# Mutually exclusive elements in XSD

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I want to implement a relationship where "Rate" element should only exists when "ComponentInstId and "ComponentInstIdServ" are not present and vice versa. How can I do that in below xsd code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Component">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="ComponentId" nillable="false">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="ComponentInstId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="ComponentInstIdServ" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Rate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not the equivalent of `(ComponentId, (Rate | (ComponentInstId, ComponentInstIdServ?)?))` ?

How important is it that the order be allowed to vary?  Does the sequence of children provide useful information?  If not, fix the sequence, just as HTML requires that `head` come before `body` instead of after.  If the sequence does provide information, you can either multiply out the possibilities, or restructure the XML.  If you make ComponentId a required attribute on Component, and Id and IdServ attributes on ComponentInst, then the content model of Component can be just `(Rate | ComponentInst)?`.

You say that "Sequence doesn't matter."  If this means "sequence conveys no information", then a declaration of the following form ensures that you will always have the Id of the component and either Rate information, or ComponentInst information, or neither.

```
<xs:element name="Component">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="Rate" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </
      <xs:element name="ComponentInst" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
         <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:attribute name="IdServ" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
        </
      </
    </
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </
</
```

(Not tested, as the absence of full end-tags is intended to suggest.)

If by "Sequence doesn't matter" you mean "it is essential that all possible sequences of the information be valid", then your content model will need to be more complicated, but it's a simple enough regular expression to work out.

[Addendum] Since some readers of Stack Overflow apparently have trouble working out problems like this, however, here is a solution that allows elements A (think: ComponentId), B (think: Rate), C (ComponentInstId), and D (ComponentInstIdServ) to appear in any order, with A required, the others optional, and with the constraint that if B occurs neither C nor D may occur.

First, let's just write out a choice of all possible sequences, in a compact notation like that of DTDs or Relax NG compact syntax:

```
( (A, B?)
| (A, C?, D?)
| (A, D?, C?)
| (B?, A)
| (C?, A, D?)
| (C?, D, A)
| (D?, A, C?)
| (D?, C, A)
)
```

This (or rather its XSD equivaslent) is not legal as it stands, however, because of 'Unique Particle Attribution' rule of XSD, so we need to factor out the various left-hand prefixes, and generally make the expression deterministic.  An instance can begin with A, B, C, or D, so first we make four deterministic expressions for those cases, which we can then put together in a choice.  If A is first:

```
( A, ( (B) | (C, D?) | (D, C?) )? )
```

If B is first:

```
(B, A?)
```

If C is first:

```
(C ( (A, D?) | (D, A) ) )
```

If D is first:

```
(D ( (A, C?) | (C, A) ) )
```

Or, all together now:

```
( ( A, ( (B) | (C, D?) | (D, C?) )? )
| (B, A?)
| (C ( (A, D?) | (D, A) ) )
| (D ( (A, C?) | (C, A) ) )
)
```

Or, in the XSD equivalent:

```
<xs:complexType name="demo">
  <xs:choice>
    <!--* we can start with A *-->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="A"/>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="B" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="C"/>
          <xs:element ref="D" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="D"/>
          <xs:element ref="C" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <!--* or we can start with B *-->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="B"/>
      <xs:element ref="A" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <!--* or we can start with C *-->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="C"/>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="A"/>
          <xs:element ref="D" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="D"/>
          <xs:element ref="A"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <!--* or we can start with D *-->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="D"/>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="A"/>
          <xs:element ref="C" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="C"/>
          <xs:element ref="A"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: please explain a bit more. Sequence doesn't matter. Model on Component is All. Cannot make ComponentId optional.

Comment: Sorry; misread the existing schema.  Have revised the answer.

Comment: 1. Elements ComponentId, ComponentInstId, ComponentInstIdServ and Rate can come in any order. Only ComponentId is manadatory here. The only dependency required is that when Rate is presnent then ComponentInstId and ComponentInstIdServ should not be there. Below are example xmls.

Comment: Valid scenario <Request>
 <Component>
  <ComponentId>1001</ComponentId>  
  <Rate>15</Rate>
 </Component>
</Request>

Comment: Valid scenario <Request>
 <Component>
  <ComponentId>1001</ComponentId>
  <ComponentInstId>154</ComponentInstId>
  <ComponentInstIdServ>2</ComponentInstIdServ>  
 </Component>
</Request>

Comment: INVALID Scenario <Request>
 <Component>
  <ComponentId>0</ComponentId>
  <ComponentInstId>0</ComponentInstId>
  <ComponentInstIdServ>0</ComponentInstIdServ>
  <Rate>0</Rate>
 </Component>
</Request>

Comment: Hmm.  You say that elements can occur in any order, but then your valid examples always put ComponentId first.  Since the requirement that elements must be allowed to occur in any order is so very often bogus, I suspect it's bogus in this case as well.  But for the cases where it is not bogus, the answer now shows step by step how to work out a solution, instead of leaving any work to the reader.